# Updating bootstrap-vue alert's content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I'd like to know how to update a Bootstrap-Vue ([Bootstrap-Vue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/alert/)) alert's content after it's shown.

This is needed in such a scenario: display an alert with a link, the user clicks the link to initiate a remote operation, the alert displays a loading indicator, the the operation completes, finally the alert displays a success message.

Comment: Post the code you've attempted so far

Answer (score 0):

It's just like updating any other reactive property. The example below shows three states... default, loading and updated.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <b-alert show>{{ alertText }}</b-alert>
    <b-btn @click="updateText">Update Text</b-btn>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      alertText: 'Default text',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateText() {
      this.alertText = 'loading'
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.alertText = Math.random()
      }, 2000)
    },
  }
}
</script>
```